# Access denied when try to get authorization code into google drive api

Tags: google-drive-api

I am developing a code where I need to access google drive API so when I am trying to get authorisation code at that time I got access denied error from google for redirect uri.

How can I solve this access denied error?

Thanks in advance.

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

Click in error details and read the info.

The trouble could be in the credentials -> Client ID for Web application -> Authorised redirect URI .